# How to go back multiple pages in ionic 3

Tags: ionic2, uinavigationbar, ionic3

I have the page flow like below:

```
A->B->C->D
```

Somehow I will do a function in page"D", after it need to go back page"B".
How can I achieve that?
Using .pop() just can go back one page.
Using .push(B) is also not the solution, because the flow will become:

```
A->B->C->D->B
```

The solution I want is:

```
A->B
```

Anyone know how to achieve it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.navCtrl.popTo(this.navCtrl.getByIndex(this.navCtrl.length()-(N+1)));
```

Where `N` is the number of pages that you want to go back.

So if you want to go back 2 pages `N=2`

Comment: Thanks, I want to use indexOf for getting the page index, but it always return -1, do you know why?
this.navCtrl.popTo(this.navCtrl.getByIndex(this.navCtrl.indexOf(B)));

Comment: `this.navCtrl.indexOf()` expects a view of type `viewController`, you are giving a page, thus -1.

Comment: Sorry I am new in ionic, may I ask what I need to put in it.

Comment: How to create a viewcontroller of B page?

Comment: Ok, to do that you need to do certain steps.

Comment: First of all you need to get the current page index, this can be done by putting an event in the `<ion-tabs (ionChange)="tabSelected($event)">`

Comment: And in the page where you need to go back call for the event, as like this           `tabSelected(tab: Tab) {
  console.log(tab.index);
}`

Comment: This way you get the index. Now by using that index navigate to the page you intend to go

Comment: I hope you understand what I said, if yes please upvote and mark this question as answered here

Comment: Or just do the below too, that's also gives you index which is simpler  `(<Tab>this.navCtrl).index`

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the popTo() method by giving the index of page in a parameter like below:

```
nav.popTo( this.navCtrl.getByIndex(1))
```