# Problem when going back in the stack in ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I'm doing my first project at Angular and I do not know how to do one thing, I've been searching but I have not found exactly what I wanted.

This estructure is the next one.
HomePage -> TutorialPage -> LoginPage

When you get to LoginPage and you give the physical back or back button that appears above to the left virtually, what I want is to return to HomePage. I have been trying different things but nothing worked for me, my problem is that I do not know how to make an event call when pressing back. Thank you

**My login.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private platform: Platform) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
      this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
    });
  }

  goToSignUp() {
    let id = this.idRecibido;
    this.navCtrl.push("SignupPage", {id});
  }

}
```

I also need it to work with the virtual button back on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The perfect solution for my problem was this.**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navCtrl.removeView(this.navCtrl.getPrevious());
  }

  goToSignUp() {
    let id = this.idRecibido;
    this.navCtrl.push("SignupPage", {id});
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the `Platform` service and subscribe to its `backButton` Observable like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private platform: Platform) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
      // Physical button pressed
    });
  }

  goToSignUp() {
    this.navCtrl.push("SignupPage");
  }

}
```

Comment: Forgive for my ignorance but where should I put that?

Comment: Ok, missing import Platform but it works, except the failure of pressing back you see how the previous page of the stack disappears, I just updated my code with what I have

Comment: Well `popToRoot` goes back to the first page in the stack (the root). Try just `pop` if you need to go to the previous page in the stack

Comment: I do not want to return to the previous one if not to the previous one of the previous one, that is, I want to take 2 steps back.

Comment: Not sure if this still work on Ionic 4, but you might want to give it a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353059/4544288